# mysql: revoke privilege "if exists"?

Tags: mysql

In a script, I want to make sure, a mysql user has no privileges at all on a specific database. So I do:

```
revoke all privileges on `testdb`.* from 'testuser'@'%'
```

But if the user does not have any privileges on this database I get this error:

```
There is no such grant defined for user 'testuser' on host '%'
```

What is absolutely correct, but my script throws an error now and stops. I do not want to make my script ignoring all errors from this statement.

So is there something like

```
revoke all privileges if exist ...
```

I could not find anything about that in the mysql manual.

Comment: You may want to run a `SHOW GRANTS` statement and only revoke the results from that query

Comment: Have you considered a [14.6.7.2 DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html) only for that condition?.

Comment: This is especially painful, if it breaks your replication.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` command has an [`-f` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force) which prevents the script from aborting on errors, so you might want to try this:

```
mysql -u myuser -f < script.sql
```

Of course this will also ignore other errors which you might not want to be ignored...

Also this unfortunately does not work in combination with the [`-e` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute).  However if you run mysql from a bash script anyway this can easily be circumvented by using a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
mysql -u myuser -f <<EOF
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ...
EOF
```